# how to split and group numbers dynamically in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

i have the following column in a dataframe which has numbers that are 6 digits and multiples of six, what i am trying to achieve is splitting the column into groups of 2 sub groups of 3 digits as there is a relationship.
This is the dataframe,

```
+------------------------+---+
|Col1                    |len|
+------------------------+---+
|001200                  |6  |
|201400                  |6  |
|401800                  |6  |
|201400401800            |12 |
|001200201400401800      |18 |
|001200201400401800801999|24 |
+------------------------+---+
```

What i am expecting is like this

```
+------------------------+-------------------------------+---+
|Col1                    |processed_column               |len|
+------------------------+-------------------------------+---+
|001200                  |001-200                        |6  |
|201400                  |201-400                        |6  |
|401800                  |401-800                        |6  |
|201400401800            |201-400,401-800                |12 |
|001200201400401800      |001-200,201-400,401-800        |18 |
|001200201400401800801999|001-200,201-400,401-800,801-999|24 |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+---+
```

One solution i can think of is to check the len and split it based on that, but then i have to keep writing the F.when condition for every length and split it accordingly.

```
df = df.withColumn(
            "processed_column",
            F.when(
                F.col("len") == 6,
                F.concat(
                    F.substring(F.col("Col1"), 0, 3),
                    F.lit("-"),
                    F.substring(F.col("Col1"), 3, 3),
                ),
            )
            .when(
                F.col("len") == 12,
                F.concat(
                    F.substring(F.col("Col1"), 0, 3),
                    F.lit("-"),
                    F.substring(F.col("Col1"), 4, 3),
                    F.lit(","),
                    F.substring(F.col("Col1"), 7, 3),
                    F.lit("-"),
                    F.substring(F.col("Col1"), 10, 3),
                ),
            )
            .otherwise(F.col("Col1")),
        )
```

is there a better way that can handle this dynamically?

Comment: use regexp_replace and then trim an extra trailing comma: `df.withColumn('processed_column', F.expr(r"rtrim(',',regexp_replace(Col1, '(\\d{3})(\\d{3})', '$1-$2,'))"))`

Comment: let me test this out and will give you feedback.

Comment: @jxc it works, appreciate if you can explain the regex syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know pyspark, but string in Python, you can do this to change all multiples of six string to the style which you asked in question.

```py
def f(s):
    return ','.join([s[i*6:i*6+3]+'-'+s[i*6+3:i*6+6] for i in range(len(s)//6)])
print(f('401800'))
print(f('201400401800'))
print(f('001200201400401800'))
print(f('001200201400401800801999'))
```

401-800
201-400,401-800
001-200,201-400,401-800
001-200,201-400,401-800,801-999

Comment: thank you for that @watfe, i was able to create a udf function using it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFunction(s):
    return ','.join([s[i*6:i*6+3]+'-'+s[i*6+3:i*6+6] for i in range(len(s)//6)])
udf_myFunction = F.udf(myFunction)
df.withColumn('new_string', udf_myFunction("Col1")).show()
```